# 'Post closed' activity should say 'Post put on hold'

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

Since we put questions 'on hold' now instead of 'closed', shouldn't the activity change to say 'Put on hold' instead of 'closed'?

[image: Screen shot of activity that says 'Post Closed']

If you look at the actual question (for reference: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/54043/product-support-studies), it says `[on hold]` because that's the language that we switched to. But when a user looks at their `Edit` history, it says `Post Closed`. Shouldn't that activity say `Put on hold`?

Comment: Yup, totally agree here. Good spot. However having a quick look on Meta StackOverflow it appears it has been [pointed out there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191692/revisions-of-a-question-still-shows-closed-instead-of-on-hold) before, but got no attention there. Perhaps it'll get some attention here though.

Comment: Agreed; how should it transition to "closed" though? Thinking either change "on hold" to "closed" after the several day window or add a second event that says "closed".

Comment: I would suggest adding a second event so that there's a distinction between the 'on hold' action and the 'closed' action.

Comment: Actually, `[On Hold]` is only temporary. If the post is not reopened within a week it changes to `[closed]`.

Comment: Right, but those are two different events and should probably be represented differently in the activity page. Especially since when I posted this, that screenshot said 'closed' but the question says 'on hold'. It has confused many users (as evidenced by users asking "why is my question closed" when it is, in fact, on hold)